# Login Form that sends login info from one website to another and logs the user in

Tags: html, forms

My Client wants a login form on his website (domain1.com) that can send users to their ShareFile site (domain2.com) and log them in automatically.

They have this on their old website but when I look at the code for the form it is pretty simple and doesn't transfer the data and submit the login info when I try it on the new site. Here is what they had as code:

```
 <div class="portal_form">
     <form method="post" action="https://domain2.com" target="_blank">
        
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        
            <button class="elementor-button">SUBMIT</button><br/>
            <p class="forgot-password"><a href="https://domain2.com/Authentication/Login#ForgotPassword" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><u>Forgot Your password?</u> </a></p>

    </form>
</div>
```

I told them that I thought the idea behind this wasn't very secure and that we should just link via buttons and/or navigation items to the login page on domain2.com.

They don't want to just link to the other website and have the user login there, they want the user to login on their domain1.com and just show up on domain2.com already logged in.

Can anyone help me do this?

Basically it is:

1. User fills out the Username and Password in a form on domain1.com and clicks Sumbit
2. That data is transferred to the Username and Password input boxes on domain2.com and the Submit button is automatically activated.
3. User is automatically logged in to domain2.com.

I am sure this probably can't be done purely via CSS and HTML and needs some JavaScript. I would be happy if you could just point me in the right direction and I can go from there.

Comment: You can't just point the form action at domain2's login url? Look at where domain2's login form goes and try pointing your form to the same url?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called `SSO (Single Sign On)` and there are various way which you can implement this.

*[Also your present solution is wrong and not secure | not proper way.]*

You can refer to `multiple ways` to implement this with the combination of `authentication protocols` as well.

You have not mentioned the inside of `architecture` (if it is centralized DB OR two different DB)

Assuming it as single DB or even if it is 2 different DB then also you will have to `match` the `user information`.

So here you can implement the `Hook/API` calls in between sharing the data on two domain.

**What you can do is:**

- `Domain1`: Check if user is valid or not.
- If user is valid then create the `session` for that user on `Domain1`
- At the same time call the `API/Hook` which you created on `Domain2`. This is to send the user information to `Domain2` and check if its valid or not.
- If `API/Hook` returns the validation true then create the same user `session` on `Domain2` with gathered information.
- In between you can implement some `authentication protocol` as well as per your need or `project architecture`.

Do refer this below doc for more information about `Single-Sign-On` (SSO):
[Single-Sign-On-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)